# Why cant i reallocate my matrix after a certain point?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am working on a problem, and part of it is storing words in a matrix which i create using malloc().

When I run out of given memory, im supposed to use realloc() and double the memory of my matrix. The code works until i reach 16+ capacity, in which case the program exits.

How can i fix this problem? I tried finding the cause, i thought somehow i might have run out of memory but it only works if the capacity comes out exactly to 16. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){


    int cap;
    printf("Give capacity: ");
    scanf("%d", &cap);

    char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char) * cap); //matrix memory allocation
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*129);
    }

    char tmp_word[129];
    int words = 0;
    int overflow = 0;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%s",tmp_word) != EOF){  //read from cmd
        matrix[words] = tmp_word;
        words++;
        printf("words stored: %d, Capacity: %d\n", words, cap);
        if (words == cap){
            printf("Limit reached, reallocating....\n");
            matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(char)*2*cap);
            for (int i = 0; i < (cap*2); ++i)
            {       
                if (matrix[i] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Memory reallocation failed due to a lack of memory\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            printf("1D reallocated\n");
            cap *= 2;   
            printf("Capacity increased\n");
                for (int i = (cap/2); i < cap; ++i)
                {
                    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*129);
                }
            printf("Succesful reallocation, new capacity: %d\n", cap);
        } 
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)  //free matrix
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong: `char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char) * cap);`.  You probably want `char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);` or `char** matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix * cap);`

Comment: General rule: If you use `sizeof(type)` in the `malloc()` call, the type should have 1 less `*` than the variable you're assinging to.

Comment: Thank you for the help, these comments helped solve my issue :)

Comment: It appears you want a re-sizable array of fixed-sized strings? `fscanf` with `"%s"` is Bad. Assigning a reasonable default is probably better then asking users to guess, which will undoubtedly confuse them (and is the point of having a resizable array.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are on a very unusual platform where `sizeof(char)` is not smaller than `sizeof(char *)`, you are writing past the bounds of your array (ie, you didn't allocate enough space).  Try:

```
char** matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix * cap); //matrix memory allocation
```

and *always* check the value returned by malloc.  Even if you expect to run on a platform that overcommits memory, it's still best practice to check the return value.

Similarly, your realloc should be:

```
matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof *matrix * 2 * cap);
```

and you should check that allocation as well.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve my issue, and I'm going to check the returned values from now on. Is `malloc(sizeof *matrix * cap)`  any different from `malloc(sizeof(char*)*cap)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

1. As you always allocate 129 bytes for the string it makes a little sense to use a double pointer. For your use case a flexible structure array member is much more suitable. It simplifies the memory allocation and deallocation (only one `realloc` and `free` needed)
2. It is also not very memory efficient to double the memory amount after every memory overflow. See why - (1)
3. Use functions for repeated tasks - do not program in the `main` function. See how it makes code simpler and easier to read.
4. Use **objects** not **types** in `sizeof`

```
typedef struct {
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
  char array[][129];
} Array;

#define STEP    64

Array *addString(Array *arr, const char *str)
{
    size_t newsize;
    if(!arr || arr -> size == arr -> used)
    {
        newsize = arr ? arr -> size + STEP : STEP;
        arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) + newsize * sizeof(arr -> array[0]));
        arr -> size = newsize;
        arr -> used = newsize == STEP ? 0 : arr -> used;
    }
    if(arr)
    {
        strncpy(arr -> array[arr -> used], str, sizeof(arr -> array[0]));
        arr -> array[arr -> used][sizeof(arr -> array[0]) - 1] = 0;
        arr -> used++;
    } 
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    Array *matrix = NULL;
    char tmp_word[129];
    int result;
    while ((result = fscanf(stdin,"%128s",tmp_word)) != EOF && result == 1)  //read from cmd
    {
        Array *tmp = addString(matrix, tmp_word);
        if(tmp)
        {
            matrix = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            /* handle memory allocation error */
        }
    }

    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

(1)

> According to legend, chess was invented by Grand Vizier Sissa Ben
> Dahir, and given as a gift to King Shirham of India. The king was so
> delighted that he offered him any reward he requested, provided that
> it sounded reasonable. The Grand Vizier requested the following: "Just
> one grain of wheat on the first square of a chessboard. Then put two
> on the second square, four on the next, then eight, and continue,
> doubling the number of grains on each successive square, until every
> square on the chessboard is reached." grains on chessboard
>
> Intuitively, King Shirham — just like almost anybody else —
> underestimated the number of grains and laughed at Sissa because he
> had asked such a small gift. When he had someone to calculate the
> total number of grains, it took more than a week before he came back
> with the solution. King Shirham undoubtedly became very pale when he
> got the answer: the aggregated number of grains on all squares of a
> chessboard would be 18.446.744.073.709.551.615 grains. This is the
> harvest of all the wheat of the world, of several decades.
>
> The story contains an important lesson: people are psychologically bad
> at dealing with exponential growth. Exponential growth shows an early
> stage of inertia during which it does not catch the eye. But suddenly,
> completely unexpected, it shows up like a tsunami, flooding everything
> and everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I always try to write in main first, to get parts right and then move everything to functions.  Im a beginner so there is always a danger that somehow i mess up my pointers if i start  with functions. I agree that doubling the memory is really innefective, but this is how im supposed to write the program :/. The exercise also states that no word is longer than 1024 characters, so eventually i will up that 129 to 1025 (because of the \0 character at the end of the word, if im correct). I can't use object as for now, unfortunately but i hope to get on this level soon